# Amazon have charged me for Prime membership without my knowledge

Tags: commerce

I recently discovered that Amazon have charged me for Prime Membership around 10 months ago. Unfortunately I have ordered a number of things from their website which were shipped using prime shipping, I just assumed next day delivery was part of their service and not an extra that I had paid for. Because of this they are refusing to refund my membership.
Do I have any grounds to take this further?

Comment: Amazon customer service is, in technical terms, 'da bomb.'  Legally you probably don't have much recourse, but a call to customer service may refund you the prime fee, even though your probably aren't entitled.

Comment: They flat out refused, and refused to extend my membership so that at the very least I could have some time to use the service that I paid for

Comment: You would have a better argument if you hadn't waited 10 months and taken advantage of the service multiple times during that period.

Comment: Sure, but I hadn't realised I'd been charged. I just found out about it. And I just assumed that next day delivery was part of their normal service when I had previously ordered stuff

Comment: I have accepted that I won't get a refund but I thought they would at least give me an extension on my membership so I can make full use of the services that I have paid for

Answer (score 3):

No

You agreed to their terms even if you don't remember doing so or didn't understand what you were agreeing to. If this was a mistake it was your mistake: not Amazon's.